# JSON file parsing gives object name rather contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I do have a JSON file I created here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d0b62425c78f98db2398ed558f92e5cf

Simply, I added this file to my project and trying to parse it. For some reason, NSLog line gives me "statement" as a result rather than the statement object. I was expecting it to give me the whole dictionary of statement object instead. I am clearly missing something here. I would appreciate any help.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"math" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

 NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@", jsonObject); //this gives me the whole JSON object correctly.

for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonObject[@"statements"]) {
        NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict);

}
```

Comment: What is the output for this : ` NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict);` ?

Comment: When you iterate through a dictionary the values returned are the keys.

Comment: @MidhunMP the output is "statement"

Comment: (And that is screwy JSON.  Normally one would expect "statements" to be an array of objects, not just a single object.)

Comment: (You're getting what one would expect, given the screwy JSON.)

Comment: @HotLicks you win. it was screwy indeed. I fixed it, now it gives me the statement correctly. I didn't see statement wasn't wrapped in an array. if you put it as an answer I will accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is screwy JSON. Normally one would expect the value of "statements" to be an array of objects, not just a single object.  When you iterate on a dictionary (JSON "object") you iterate through the keys, so you're getting what would be expected.

Comment: thanks, one question about my JSON. so I changed it and now in my for loop when I do NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict[@"expression"]);
I get NULL. if I do NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict[@"statement"]); however, I get the statement object like I want. Isn't this redundant? Did I structure my JSON bad? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ilteris - "expression" is inside "statement".  To access "expression" you must first get the dictionary for "statement".

Comment: in other words with  for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonObject[@"statements"]) I assume I am already iterating through my statement objects. why do I still need to reference them with dict[@"statement"]?

Comment: @ilteris - I don't know how exactly your restructured your JSON, but if "statements" contains an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary contains a "statement" element, and that element contains an "expression" element, you must "peel the onion" in that order.

Comment: yes it's structured just like you stated. I guess then question is, if the statement element redundant there. Because each dictionary is supposed to be a statement. They are supposed to be array of dictionaries.

Comment: @ilteris - It may well be that your "statement" layer is redundant.  It's up to you to decide how you want the JSON structured, and why.

Comment: that's exactly what I am thinking but I am not sure how to get rid off that while maintaining the dictionary. I don't really need to reference it, all I care is the contents of it and to know that it's wrapped in a dictionary.

Comment: oh I just deleted it :D ok thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like the dictionary containing "statement" contains nothing else, so you could eliminate that dictionary and directly include the dictionary containing "expression" in your "statements" array.